# the following sdk component was not installed sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21

Tags: android, installation, package

When I installed Android Studio and tried to run it it gives me the followig error:

```
the following sdk component was not installed sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21
```

I know there are post asking the exact same question , but all of them have recieved this error by trying to upgrade their Android Studio. Nevertheless in my case I had the last version of Android Studio and I uninstalled it , then I installed the first version of Android Studio (which is Android Studio 1.0) and I'm recieving this error. So what is the solution to my problem in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I followed this [link](http://collectionexperience.blogspot.com/2014/12/solved-android-studio-install-problem.html)